# Different Site name and slogan for Organic Groups based multisite architechture

Tags: organic-groups

I am using OG based multisite in Drupal. I need to override sitename and slogan of default values so that each organic group has its own set of system values like Sitename and slogan etc.Also I am using Variable and OG Variable modules which seem to be for this purpose, but changing variable Realms in Organic groups variables doesn't save the values, the admin form for changing variable values doesnt save values. What am i missing?any help?

Answer (score 1):

Open Atrium (6.x) uses [spaces](https://drupal.org/project/spaces) to save different configuration for each og, this may be helpful.

> Spaces is an API module intended to make configuration options
>   generally avaliable only at the sitewide level to be configurable and
>   overridden by individual "spaces" on a Drupal site. It has been
>   described as:
>
> A way to make one Drupal site act like several sites A way to provide
>   much more configurable, full-feature Organic Groups or user homepages
>   A generalized API for contextual configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can use og_context() in preprocessing or page.tpl to check if the node is a group or groupcontent and override slogan/name that way.

(this is for og 2 /drupal 7 btw. You didn't mention your version)